# how to parse code with C#. Code in brackets are standard names

Tags: c#

I have code like:

```
(00)1234567891234(10)1234(3100)12315
```

Code in brackets are standard names and are always the same. But order can be different. (10) can be before (00) and instead of (3100) can be (01)

What is the best solution to pars data like:

```
(00)1234567891234
(10)1234
(3100)12315
```

and then if i write

> 00 i will get 1234567891234
>
> 10 i will get 1234
>
> 3100 i will get 12315

what is the best aproach for doing this and how? How can i get value between ()xx()?

Comment: What have you tried? It is also not clear if the data has line breaks between key-value pairs or not.

Comment: i try with indexOf which is bad idea. code has no line breaks.

Comment: Have you looked at `String.Split`?

Comment: i was looking split yes but i am bad with regex

Comment: `String.Split` doesn't use RegEx.

Comment: `\([0-9]+\)[0-9]+` is the regex you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    const string text = "(00)1234567891234(10)1234(3100)12315";

    var result =  Regex.Matches(text, @"\((\d+)\)(\d+)").Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => new {Value = x.Groups[2].Value, Key = x.Groups[1].Value})
        .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, x => x.Value);

    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", r.Key, r.Value);
    }


    /* OUTPUT
     * 
     *  Key: 00, Value: 1234567891234
        Key: 10, Value: 1234
        Key: 3100, Value: 12315
     */

    Console.Read();
```

Using Linq (which seems to be preferable here) in one line you get a `Dictionary<string, string>` with an object that has two properties `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: very nice!  I like the approach!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple approach:

```
string input = "(00)1234567891234(10)1234(3100)12315";
string[] lines = input.Split(new [] {"("}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string ln in lines)
{
    string key = ln.Substring(0, ln.IndexOf(')'));
    string value = ln.Substring(ln.IndexOf(')') + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't write code for you but will give you a hint

`(00)1234567891234(10)1234(3100)12315`

parse above string based on `(` and this `)` you can use `String.Split` method for this

this will give you following in a array

```
00
1234567891234
10
1234
3100
12315
```

Now you can pair these value and put them in a `Dictionary<String, String>`